# Fill the rest of DIV tag space height with Input Box

Tags: html, css

At the moment this is an image of the idea I have:

[image]

The Black box around it is a DIV tag which styling looks like this:

```
#middlesection {
    height: 481px;
}
```

I have the Calender, TITLE input box and then the User Input box at the bottom.

**When you select a new month on the Calender, if that month has less days it will use less space meaning that the input box at the bottom wont fit the div anymore**

When I try and set the input box to have a height of a 100% it uses the whole screen and not the DIV size (Even though its inside that DIV)

CSS for the 3 control :

```
#calender_control {
    width: 835px !important;
}

#txt_headernotes {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color: orange;  
}

#txt_displayinformation {
    width: 100%;
    height: 12.5%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: orange;
}
```

**How can I make the Input box at the bottom to stay to the height of the div if the calender has less days it will expand if it has more it will shrink.**

HTML code:

```
<div id="middlesection">
     <DayPilot:DayPilotMonth ID="calender_control" CssClassPrefix="bsimplexcalender"
      OnCommand="calender_control_Command" ContextMenuID="menu"   
      EventRightClickHandling="ContextMenu" EventRightClickJavaScript="select(e)" 
      BubbleID="DayPilotBubble1" ClientObjectName="dpm" runat="server" 
      Theme="bsimplexcalender" HeightSpec="Auto" Height="0" MinCellHeight="63" 
      DataStartField="start" DataEndField="end" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="id" 
      OnBeforeEventRender="calender_control_BeforeEventRender" />
     <input runat="server" id="txt_headernotes" placeholder="Notes" />
     <input runat="server" id="txt_displayinformation" />
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean that `#txt_displayinformation` should be a `textarea` field (multi-line) instead of an input field (single line)? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @MarcAudet I have changed that already, but now yes the textarea top needs to be against the #txt_Headernotes and the bottom to the bottom of the div at all times so its locked in, then if the calender has less days it expands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using jQuery. When the document is ready, the text area is adjusted to fill the space below the "calendar" and "title" sections.

```
  <div id="outer">
     <div id="calendar"></div>
     <div id="title"></div>
     <div id="variable">
        <textarea name="txt-test"></textarea>
     </div>
  </div>

  <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

  <script>
     function resizeTextArea() {
        var outerHeight = $('#outer').height();
        var calendarHeight = $('#calendar').height();
        var titleHeight = $('#title').height();

        $('#variable').each(function () {
           var textContainer = $(this);
           textContainer.height(outerHeight - (calendarHeight + titleHeight));
           textContainer.find('textarea').height(textContainer.height()).width(textContainer.width());
        });
     }

     $(function () {
        resizeTextArea();
     });

  </script>
```

And some test CSS:

```
  <style>
     #outer {
        height: 480px;
        border: 2px solid black;
     }

     #calendar {
        height: 200px;
        background-color: blue;
     }

     #title {
        height: 40px;
        background-color: green;
     }

     #variable {
        background-color: red;
        overflow: hidden;
     }

        #variable textarea {
        }

  </style>
```

Comment: Does jQuery have to be used?

Comment: You can do plain JavaScript but jQuery will certainly simplify it a bit. I use jQuery because I'm terrible at native JavaScript.

Comment: I have added the code and it doesn't work still. I was wondering is there a way of checking the size; so if the height of the calender is 398px it makes the size of the text area 125px and when the calender hits 398px the text area goes to 62px?

Comment: Try to use the code I provided in isolation. I did test it on my computer. If you still have issues, try to determine the script error you are receiving. Did you reference jQuery?

Comment: OK let me host the working page somewhere, and then you can grab it from there.

Answer (score 0):

one way to achieve this would be to use absolute positioning.

As your div wrapper has a set height this won't cause any unexpected problems.

**HTML**

```
<div id="middlesection">
    <DayPilot:DayPilotMonth CssClassPrefix="bsimplexcalender" OnCommand="calender_control_Command" ContextMenuID="menu" EventRightClickHandling="ContextMenu" EventRightClickJavaScript="select(e)" BubbleID="DayPilotBubble1" ClientObjectName="dpm" runat="server" ID="calender_control" Theme="bsimplexcalender" HeightSpec="Auto" Height="0" MinCellHeight="63" DataStartField="start" DataEndField="end" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="id" OnBeforeEventRender="calender_control_BeforeEventRender" />
    <div id="INPUTBOX">
        <input runat="server" id="txt_headernotes" placeholder="Notes" />
        <input runat="server" id="txt_displayinformation" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#middlesection{
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:200px; /*Set to height of input*/
}    
#INPUTBOX {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height:400px;
}
```

Comment: This just moves my input out of the div tag and doesnt stay its position.